# Search for answers that have been awarded bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounties, search

We can search for accepted answers.  But can we search for answers that were awarded bounties? If not, we should be able to.

Answers that earn a bounty are often of interest for being notably deep or esoteric, as necessitating the bounty in the first place.  I feel that it would be beneficial to find these posts more easily.  There already advanced search operators for number of answers, number of views, score, etc.; this seems to be of a similar nature and should not be difficult to implement.

Comment: Why would this be useful?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I was just looking for an answer of mine that I got a bounty for (not the accept check, just a bounty). It would have made finding it much easier than trying to remember the phrasing of the question or answer.

Comment: Ah. You can go here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas?tab=bounties&sort=earned

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to search questions with bounties (ever having had a bounty)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157195/is-there-a-way-to-search-questions-with-bounties-ever-having-had-a-bounty)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because it is the feature request for this feature.

Comment: It's also older