# Is there a way to search questions with bounties (ever having had a bounty)?

Tags: support, search, bounties

I have a problem on SE in finding a question (and valuable answers) that has been listed on the "Featured" tab for some days. Now it's disappeared from this tab, presumably because bounty period is over, and I'm trying to find it by tag, but this gives too many irrelevant questions, so I gave up.

The question: is it possible to search (filter) questions that currently have, or ever have had a bounty?

Comment: Add `hasnotice:1` to your search criteria.

Comment: @AzizShaikh - I think this may not work. Because he wants `hadnotice:1`. :)

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, but got very few questions, and half of them are not marked by bounty.

Comment: @AzizShaikh - No. It shows that question in the result because it **has** bounty worth 200 rep. by [RoflcoptrException](http://stackoverflow.com/users/329637/roflcoptrexception?tab=bounties&sort=active).

Comment: @AzizShaikh - Once the grace period is over, the question will not be listed in the search result.

Comment: @AzizShaikh - Proof. [Search result for `[programming-languages] [haskell] [modeling] [functional-programming]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages+haskell+modeling+functional-programming) shows 1 question which had a bounty while search result for [`[programming-languages] [haskell] [modeling] [functional-programming] hasnotice:1`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprogramming-languages%5D+%5Bhaskell%5D+%5Bmodeling%5D+%5Bfunctional-programming%5D+hasnotice%3A1) shows 0 question. :)

Comment: @hims056 As you correctly mentioned, **notice** was removed from the post.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history is another proposal to make past bounties more visible.

Comment: A recent related post: [List of past bounties on a SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307406#307426)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can use a query on data.stackexchange.com like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/648267/list-bounties) to find all bounties started on a site.

This query works for any Stack Exchange site, just choose the "Switch sites" option (this example uses SE Meta).  The first four columns show information about the question, the last five show information about the bounty.  The bounties are listed in order of their creation, from most recent to oldest.  This does not show whether the bounty has ended or what it was awarded to.

Note that the dump used by data.stackexchange.com can be several days old, so the listing may miss some of the most recent bounties.

Comment: Really cool and useful.