# How can see list all the questions which had a bounty on them?

Tags: support, bounties

Is it possible to see a list of questions which had a bounty?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307406/list-of-past-bounties-on-a-se-site#307426

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is available in SEDE; for example, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1053766/questions-with-bounties) lists all 4688 bounties on this site. Since a question might be bountied multiple times, there are duplicates in the list, but I'm not sure if you mind.

[image]

Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/fork/1053766) the query to suit it to your own needs.

Comment: It worked like a charm. There should be a search operator for this. Like bounty:1 true for this type of search @Glorfindel