# Cataloging Canonical Answers

Tags: discussion, canonical

I was dismayed to find this (now old) feature-request declined: [Another take on canonical answers: Add a "canonical" vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116087/241697) (... and this similar feature-request yet-to-be-addressed: [Canonical answers for repeated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108579/241697))

On smaller sites like, say, [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/), there are occasionally truly outstanding answers that will not only address many future questions, but also be useful references in answers to questions they do not fully cover.  (E.g., [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/2278/10) or [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/2072/10).)  But there is no clear or established way of keeping track of these, or even finding them when I myself remember that, "Hey, there was a really great answer that covers this."  (Heck, I can't even [Favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221729/241697) an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569/241697).)

One way that *might* work is to use bounties as an indicator, but not until the following feature is implemented: [Search for answers that have been awarded bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127683/241697)

**My inclination in the interim is to open a "Canonical Answers" community-wiki question in Meta where a list could simply be accumulated.**

But first I want to make sure I'm not missing some other feature or convention that would better address this need.

---

**tl;dr:**

1. It would be useful to be able to mark and find "canonical" answers
2. Is there an existing feature or mechanism to do this?
3. If not, does a community-wiki "Canonical Answers" question on a site's Meta seem like the best solution?
4. If not, can you propose something better, or at least explain why that's a bad idea?

Comment: I find your question unclear. If you want to discuss how to create a canonical answer list for law.se you better ask that on the meta of law.se. If you post here to get those declined FR's reversed you have to bring something new to the table. Until you decided which way this question needs to go you might get down votes. More generic said: the unclear reason applies.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, people probably disagree with what you suggest (catalog of canonical answers) and/or find your question not clear enough, as @rene said.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to start archive of great answers in the per-site meta it's fine in my opinion. We have kind of archive here in MSE already: [Deleted Meta Questions Archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-meta-questions-archive)

As for the declined feature request, you can try bumping it with bounty or edit, explaining why you think the team should reconsider, and there is a chance (small, but still) that it might happen.

Comment: I learned something new today... +1 for "Deleted Meta Questions Archive"